# how to download an image from webcontrol using c# without the exact image url

Tags: c#, web-controls

I have made a program to download an image automatically.  I pass the html code ,I see the SRC attribute of the IMG html element is not the exact image file url ,it is like the following:

```
<img id="door2img" width="450" height="50"
      src="/pincode/pin1.php?lang=zh&amp;r=1309587154480&amp;rule">
```

It is confusing, I am using c# webcontrol for programming. I can get the img html element,how can I dowload the image in such a situation,because there's not the image url?

Answer (score 1):

Extract the value of the src attribute and append it to the base url (i.e. in http://some.site.com/section/page?id=5 the base url would be http://some.site.com). Pass that string to WebClient.DownloadFile or WebClient.DownloadData and you'll get what you need.

Comment: But It is not successful.I can get the url as you point,but this url seems not the real image url,so when I use WebClient.DownloadFile or WebClient.DownloadData,it will return null. any more suggestion,thank you.

Comment: Make sure you've got the same cookies. On top of that if it's a captcha it might only be requestable once